# Erro ao usar método de entrada em função com Python

Tags: python

Estou com um problema em meu código. Tenho 3 funções, uma delas usa um método de entrada chamado tweet porém quando eu chamo a função da erro e não executa, talvez não tenha entendido direito essa parte de métodos de entrada mas revisei algumas vezes e para mim parece estar certo.

Faço a leitura de um arquivo com essa função:

```
def le_tweets():
    lista = []
    file = codecs.open("tweets_prova.txt", encoding='utf-8')
    for l in file:
        lista.append(l.replace('\n',''))
    return lista
```

Pego o valor da função anterior e retorno para por numa variável depois

```
def carregaTweets():
        lista = ''
        lista = le_tweets()
        return lista
```

E essa função para separar o texto por palavras

```
def separa_palavras(tweet):
    return tweet.split(' ')
```

Eu consigo receber o texto do arquivo que eu li, porém quando uso a separa_palavras(tweet) da erro e eu não sei o que mudar para resolver.

```
tweet = carregaTweets()
lista = separa_palavras(tweet)
print(lista)
```

Comment: Qual é o erro? Seja mais específico

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jhonatan.teodoro\Desktop\trabalho\atividade_raaluno1_raaluno2.py", line 58, in <module>
    lista = (separa_palavras(tweet))
  File "C:\Users\jhonatan.teodoro\Desktop\trabalho\atividade_raaluno1_raaluno2.py", line 23, in separa_palavras
    return tweet.split(' ')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu método `carregaTweets()` retorna uma lista de strings. Portanto, `separa_palavras(tweet)` recebe uma lista de strings por parâmetro. Você está tentando chamar `split` na lista toda, sendo que você não pode dar `split` em uma lista, somente em uma string.

Comment: Entendi. Vou tentar fazer aqui, obrigado cara!

Comment: Consegui man, obrigado!!

Comment: Fico feliz em ter ajudado, @JhonatanTeodoro. Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, por favor considere marcar como *aceita*.